# Calculating the mean from cell reference variables within csv

Tags: r, mean, calculation

I am new to R and am learning on the go so please excuse some ignorance on my part. I have attempted to write what i am after but I'm hitting a few roadblocks along the way...

I have adapted this code from a colleague to determine different phases of a force-time trace. Code is below. It reads the csv and then exports with frame reference with new csv.

Each phase of the trace is defined due to specific rules.

However, i want to know the mean sum.force, mean velocity and mean power between start.propulsion and end.propulsion? The output of start and end propulsion are cell references rather than data values.

Secondly, how can i write a loop in the code so i can direct the code to read 40 csv files from one folder, and generate 40 csv files with the desired output?

Folder = Common2\Desktop\R\Jump_Files

Thanks in advance.

D

I am having trouble writing the mean formula to generate the value. I know it will be something like

> mean.force  = mean(start.propulsion:end.propulsion)

but this doesn't seem to be working? I know it has something to do with using values rather than cell reference but i am stuck at this point

Question below the code...

```
# load required packages
 require(readr)
 library(tidyverse)
getwd()

# import data frame
filename <- "P01_CMJ_T01.csv"
datapath <- ''
Jump.1 = read_csv(
  paste0(datapath, filename),
  col_names = TRUE,
  skip = 3,
  trim_ws = TRUE
)


# add rownumber
Jump.1$row = 1:nrow(Jump.1)

# rename variable, sub frame to time
names(Jump.1) <- c('Frame','Time','F1','F2','sum.force','row.number')



# find sample rate
Sample.rate = 1 / diff(Jump.1$Time[1:2], lag = 1, differences = 1)

# find body mass
BM = mean(Jump.1$sum.force[1:Sample.rate])
BM.kg = BM / 9.81
sd = sd(Jump.1$sum.force[1:Sample.rate])

# add variables
Jump.1 = mutate(Jump.1, net.force    = Jump.1$sum.force - BM)
Jump.1 = mutate(Jump.1, acceleration = Jump.1$net.force / BM.kg)

# velocity
Jump.1$change_vel = (Jump.1$acceleration + lag(Jump.1$acceleration, 1)) / 2 * c(NA, diff(Jump.1$Time))
Jump.1$velocity = c(0, rep(NA, nrow(Jump.1) - 1))
for (i in 2:nrow(Jump.1)) {
  Jump.1$velocity[i] <- Jump.1$velocity[i - 1] + Jump.1$change_vel[i]
}

#power
Jump.1 = mutate(Jump.1, power = Jump.1$velocity * Jump.1$sum.force)

# ******************************************************************************
# Start of unweighting phase - BM - 5sd 
## [only flag if remain below threshold for samplerate/10 rows]
threshold = BM - 5 * sd

# Get all the rows less than threshold
start.unweighting = which(Jump.1$sum.force < threshold)
#show(start.unweighting)

# Finds all the sub-sequences
subseq <- split(start.unweighting, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(start.unweighting) != 1)))
#show(subseq)

# Throw away the sub-sequences less than samplerate/10 length
subseq <- subseq[sapply(subseq, length) >= Sample.rate / 10]
#show(subseq)

# The start of unweighing is then the first row of the first sub-sequence
start.unweighting <- subseq[[1]][1]
show(start.unweighting)

# ******************************************************************************
# End of unweighting phase

# All rows > theshold and AFTER start-unweigh
end.unweighting = which(Jump.1$sum.force > threshold & Jump.1$row.number > start.unweighting)
#show(end.unweighting)

# Finds all the sub-sequences
subseq <- split(end.unweighting, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(end.unweighting) != 1)))
#show(subseq)

# Throw away the sub-sequences less than samplerate/10 length
subseq <- subseq[sapply(subseq, length) >= Sample.rate / 10]
#show(subseq)

end.unweighting <- subseq[[1]][1] - 1
show(end.unweighting)

# ******************************************************************************
# Start braking
start.braking = end.unweighting + 1
show(start.braking)

# ******************************************************************************
# End braking
# All rows with vel > 0 and AFTER start braking
end.braking = which(Jump.1$velocity > 0 &
                      Jump.1$row.number > start.braking)[1] - 1
show(end.braking)

# ******************************************************************************
# Start propulsion phase - vel > 0 > e
start.propulsion = end.braking + 1
show(start.propulsion)

# ******************************************************************************
# End propulsion
end.propulsion = which(Jump.1$sum.force < threshold &
                         Jump.1$row.number > start.propulsion)[1] - 1
show(end.propulsion)

# ******************************************************************************
# Start flight
start.flight = end.propulsion + 1
mid.flight = which(Jump.1$sum.force == 0 &
                     Jump.1$row.number > start.flight)[1]
# ******************************************************************************
# End flight
end.flight = which(Jump.1$sum.force > 10 -1 &
                     Jump.1$row.number > mid.flight)[1]

# ******************************************************************************
# Flight.time
Flight.time = (end.flight - start.flight) * 0.001
show(Flight.time)

# ******************************************************************************
# Jump.height from flight time
Jump.height = (0.125 * 9.8 * Flight.time^2)
show(Jump.height)

 ******************************************************************************
# Write output
output <- data.frame(
  event = c(
    'unweighting.start',
    'unweighting.end',
    'braking-start',
    'braking-end',
    'propulsion.start',
    'propulsion.end',
    'flight.start',
    'flight.end',
    'flight.time',
    'jump.height'
  ),
  frame = NA
)
output$frame[1] <- Jump.1$Frame[start.unweighting]
output$frame[2] <- Jump.1$Frame[end.unweighting]
output$frame[3] <- Jump.1$Frame[start.braking]
output$frame[4] <- Jump.1$Frame[end.braking]
output$frame[5] <- Jump.1$Frame[start.propulsion]
output$frame[6] <- Jump.1$Frame[end.propulsion]
output$frame[7] <- Jump.1$Frame[start.flight]
output$frame[8] <- Jump.1$Frame[end.flight]
output$frame[9] <- Flight.time
output$frame[10] <- Jump.height
show(output)


write.csv(output,
          file = paste0('output-', sub('.xlsx', '.csv', filename)))
```

Comment: Please supply `"P01_CMJ_T01.csv"` or equivalent.

Comment: Frame Sub Frame Fz Fz sum force
  N N N
1 0.001 -418.764 -438.583 857.347
1 0.002 -419.594 -438.176 857.77
1 0.003 -419.543 -438.633 858.176
1 0.004 -418.803 -438.494 857.297
2 0.005 -418.484 -438.405 856.889
2 0.006 -418.714 -439.051 857.765
2 0.007 -418.854 -439.737 858.591
2 0.008 -419.363 -439.459 858.822
3 0.009 -419.823 -439.001 858.824
3 0.01 -419.823 -439.14 858.963
3 0.011 -419.404 -439.369 858.773
3 0.012 -419.413 -439.508 858.921
4 0.013 -420.004 -439.598 859.602
4 0.014 -419.083 -439.092 858.175
4 0.015 -419.223 -438.772 857.995
4 0.016 -419.593 -439.279 858.87

Comment: That didn;t really work. Columns, A>E, Frame, Sub frame, Fz, Fz1, Sum force